# How to get the last elements of the values of selected keys of a dictionary in DolphinDB?

Tags: dictionary, dolphindb

```
dt=dict(STRING,ANY)
dt[`AAPL]=10 11 12
dt[`AMZN]=61 62 63
dt[`NFLX]=34 35 36 37;
```

For this dictionary in DolphinDB, how can I take the last element of the value for AAPL and NFLX to get the vector [12,37]?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def f(d, symbols){
    return each(x->d[x].tail(), symbols)
}
f(dt, `AAPL`NFLX);
```